# MS Chart XValueType

Tags: c#, mschart

I am using a single Chart control from MS Chart to show XValueType as Time and Double. If I choose to show Double at first, it works fine. But when I am trying to show double value after showing time values in the chart. Its x-Axis values are not shown, although they have values. I tried LabelStyle.Format = "0.0". It does not work. Can any body help? 
Thanks in advance for any help....

Answer (score 1):

I just found a solution to my question. Actually I was using the same chartarea to show two different types of XValueType. 
I just Cleared the chartarea and added to a new chartarea to the chart and thats it my problem is solved.

If anybody falls into a situation like this, you may consider this as a solution.